# Create a new path item in Adobe Illustrator via JXA (JavaScript for Automation)

Tags: macos, scripting, adobe-illustrator, javascript-automation

I'm looking for a way to create path items in Adobe Illustrator using JXA (JavaScript for Automation). I googled the whole internet several times and couldn't find anything... There is only a very basic introduction of JXA on the Apple Developer Site: [JavaScript for Automation Release Notes (10.10)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW1)
Adobe doesn't cover this subject at all.
Here is my code, where I tried to add an ellipse to an existing document:

```
illuApp = Application('Illustrator')
docPath = "/Users/userOne/Desktop/Document_One.ai"
illuApp.open(docPath)

currentDoc = illuApp.currentDocument
console.log(currentDoc.name())

// Ellipse constructor
newEllipse = illuApp.Ellipse({left: 512.5, top: 87.5, width: 425.0, height: 75.0, reversed: false, inscribed: true})

// This doesn't work **(Error -1700: Can't convert types.)**
currentDoc.pathItems.push(newEllipse)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't waste your time. Like ScriptingBridge before it, JXA doesn't work right: it'll do simple stuff up to a point…then it craps out on you; at which point you're screwed. Apple have never documented or supported it for shit, and it's failed to build even a fraction of the audience that AS has, so I wouldn't be surprised it it's first on the hit list if/when Apple roll out their revised automation strategy. (There's a reason the last Automation Project Manager got fired. I daresay we'll have a better idea after June 9th.)

If you want to automate AI using JavaScript, use its built-in JavaScript (JSX) interpreter. Otherwise stick to AppleScript it's the only officially *supported* option that knows how to speak Apple events right†. This is especially important when writing non-trivial scripts, as poorer AE bridges are most likely run out of steam/break on compatibility bugs when automating large, complex, aged scriptable apps like Illustrator, Excel, FileMaker, etc.

---

† There is also [py-appscript/SwiftAutomation](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/), (which is what I use for my own high-end Illustrator automation, and comprehensively kicks AppleScript's ass too), but after years of Apple's screwing about I no longer recommend or provide support for it, so you would be on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That sounds quite sobering... Maybe June 9th brings some good news :)